# Change row color of a table based on mysqli value using materializecss

Tags: php, css, mysql, html, materialize

I'm using Materialize css on my project, i have a table that shows mysql field called "status" and in this table i want change the color of the row if i change the "status" like "1=blue, 2=red..." Someone here knows how i can make a function to do this? Thank you.

table extample:

```
table class="striped bordered responsive-table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Objeto</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($row_os = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)){?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["num"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["object"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["status"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `if ($row_os["status"] == 1) { addRequiredColor }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way would be:

```
<?php 
$colorMap = [
  1 => 'blue',
  2 => 'red',
  // add more
];
while ($row_os = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)) { ?>
<tr style="background:<?php echo $colorMap[$row_os['status']] ?>">
    <td><?php echo $row_os["num"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["object"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["status"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Of course you could also add a `class` depending on status the same way and do the styling in CSS.

Comment: And for change the background of the row? is the same way?

Comment: This is already for the background. And of course you can use any CSS you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as Doing this on the row , only if the status must contain a value of either **1** or **2**

```
<?php
 while($row_os = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)){?>
<tr class="<?php echo $row_os["status"]==1?'blue':'red'?> lighten-2">
    <td><?php echo $row_os["num"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["cliente"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["object"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_os["status"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

or if status varies (then follow @colburton answers ) or this

```
 <?php
     while($row_os = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user)){
    $color="";
    switch($row_os["status"]){
    case 1:
    $color="blue";
    break;
    case 2:
    $color="red";
    break;
    //and so on
    }
    ?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $color;?> lighten-2">
        <td><?php echo $row_os["num"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_os["cliente"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_os["object"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_os["status"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```